# Conditional statements in "WHERE" in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, subquery, where-clause

What I want to achieve is to have a switch case in the where clause. I want to test if this statement returns something, if it returns null, use this instead.

Sample:

```
SELECT [THIS_COLUMN] 
FROM [THIS_TABLE]  
WHERE (IF THIS [ID] RETURNS NULL THEN DO THIS SUBQUERY)
```

What I mean is that it will do this query first.

```
SELECT [THIS_COLUMN] 
FROM [THIS_TABLE]  
WHERE [ID] = 'SOMETHING'
```

If this returns `NULL`, do this query instead:

```
SELECT [THIS_COLUMN] 
FROM [THIS_TABLE]  
WHERE ID = (SELECT [SOMETHING] FROM [OTHER_TABLE] 
            WHERE [SOMETHING_SPECIFIC] = 'SOMETHING SPECIFIC')
```

Note that the expected results from the intended query varies from 30 rows up to 15k rows. Hope it helps.

Adding more information:

The results for this query will be used for another query but will just focus on this query.
Providing a real case scenario:

`[THIS_COLUMN]` is expected to have a list of VALUES.

`[THIS_TABLE]` contains the latest data only(let's say 1 year's worth of data) while the `[OTHER_TABLE]` contains the historical data.

What I want to achieve is when I query for a data that is not with in the 1 year's worth of data, IE `'SOMETHING'` is not with in the 1 year scope(or in my case it returns `NULL`), I will use the other query where I query the `'SOMETHING_SPECIFIC'`(Or may be '`SOMETHING'` from the first statement makes more sense) from the historical table.

Comment: Neither ISO SQL and T-SQL support any kind of conditional predicates in the `WHERE` clause. You have to use Dynamic SQL or a multi-step query batch (e.g. a stored procedure).

Comment: You *could* use a `NOT EXISTS`

Comment: @Larnu `NOT EXISTS` doesn't have the same semantics as `IS NOT NULL`. Though things get weird as the original query returns a scalar.

Comment: Think you missed my point, @Dai , I've added an answer to demonstrate.

Comment: @Larnu I have read your answer, but I don't see how you think I'm "missing the point": `NOT EXISTS ( SELECT 1)` still has different semantics. I note that your posted answer uses `OR` at the top-level query whereas the OP's question doesn't say that `OR` would necessarily be correct.

Comment: Which is why the `NOT EXISTS` is there, @Dai .

Comment: *"`[THIS_COLUMN]` is expected to have a list of VALUES."* Well there's your first problem, you have a design problem. A single row in a column contains a single value, not many. Sounds like you are storing delimited data in a column; which needs fixing.

Comment: What I meant was the results of the query is expected to have a list of values if I could apply a conditional statement in the where clause where in like when this condition returns a `NULL` value, use the results of this query instead.

Answer (score 1):

If I as reading through the lines correctly, this *might* work:

```sql
SELECT THIS_COLUMN 
FROM dbo.THIS_TABLE TT
WHERE TT.ID = 'SOMETHING'
   OR TT.ID = (SELECT OT.SOMETHING
               FROM dbo.OTHER_TABLE OT
               WHERE OT.SOMETHING_SPECIFIC = 'SOMETHING SPECIFIC'
                AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                                FROM dbo.THIS_TABLE sq
                                WHERE sq.ID = 'SOMETHING'
                                  AND THIS_COLUMN IS NOT NULL))
```

Note, however, that this could easily not be particularly performant.

Comment: There might be a case where the `OR` statement would cause issues as `TT.ID = 'SOMETHING'` and the `OR TT.ID = (SELECT ...` would be both be true and the results may be not the expected values.

Comment: I can't think of scenario what the `NOT EXISTS` would not return a row and `TT.ID = 'SOMETHING'` would, @Dense04 . When can `TT.ID = 'SOMETHING'` **AND** *not*?

Comment: Provided more details on the main post. @Larnu

Answer (score 1):

You an use `union all` and `not exists`:

```
select this_column 
from this_table  
where id = 'something'
union all
select this_column 
from this_table 
where 
    not exists (select this_column from this_table where id = 'something')
    and id = (select something from other_table where something_specific = 'something specific')
```

The first `union` member attempts to find rows that match the first condition, while the other one uses the subquery - the `not exists` prevents the second member to return something if the first member found a match.

Answer (score 0):

90% of the time you *can* use a query-batch (i.e. a sequence of T-SQL statements) in a single `SqlCommand` object or SQL Server client session, so with that in-mind you could do this:

```
DECLARE @foo nvarchar(50) = (
    SELECT
        [THIS_COLUMN] 
    FROM
        [THIS_TABLE]  
    WHERE
        [ID] = 'SOMETHING'
);

IF @foo IS NULL
BEGIN

    SELECT
        [THIS_COLUMN] 
    FROM
        [THIS_TABLE]
    WHERE
        [ID] = (
            SELECT
                [SOMETHING]
            FROM
                [OTHER_TABLE] 
            WHERE
                [SOMETHING_SPECIFIC] = 'SOMETHING SPECIFIC'
        )

END
ELSE
BEGIN

    SELECT @foo AS [THIS_COLUMN];

END
```

That said, `SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE x IN ( SELECT y FROM ... )` is a code-smell in a query - you probably need to rethink your solution entirely.

Comment: This seems to be a viable solution. I haven't tried batches yet since the query is executed in a python script but I think that might not be an issue and requesting the to have a stored proc created would be a headache as this project has low priority.

Comment: Also adding, `[THIS_COLUMN]` is not a single value. It varies from as low as 30 rows up to 15k rows. Updating my main post.